# Are sites using AMP pages losing google analytics tracking to third party sites?

Tags: wordpress, caching, google-analytics, amp-html

My wife and I run a WordPress blog that utilizes the AMP plugin. AMP versions of posts are automatically created. Though I may have read somewhere that AMP caches can be shared with anyone, it did not occur to me until now that other sites can display our AMP content as a cached page of their site and we never get credit for the visit.

Just today, a blogger friend mentioned that she saw traffic in her Google Analytics from https://cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.mommypotamus.com/how-to-buy-a-non-toxic-mattress/amp/?amp_js_v=5

This is a cached version of our web page located at http://www.mommypotamus.com/how-to-buy-a-non-toxic-mattress/amp/

She is seeing referral traffic from a third party site containing our content. We have no Google Analytics record for this traffic or that third party page. So my question is:

Am I losing the credit for traffic passing through third party sites? And how are people even getting to them?

This matters because we just launched AdThrive ads on our site last week, and with mobile being approx 70% of traffic, we are losing money due to AMP. I realize that some ad networks are already compatible with AMP, but AdThrive is not, due to the fact that they employ real-time bidding on ad spots, which delivers maximum earnings to the publisher.

Maybe more sites are sharing cached versions of our AMP pages, but we know at least that Google Cache is doing so and AmpProject is doing so. How is that content tracked in GA? If it isn't, how is that supposed to be okay?

AMP is starting to feel like I've given someone permission to scrape all my content and outrank my actual site with my own content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related might be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'm seeing this as well and source appearing as cdn.ampproject.org in Ga when really in this case it should be mommypotamus.com. 

feels like this is a problem that will only get bigger over time. 

curious how others are dealing with it - cant seem to find much when googleing it

Answer (score 0):

cdn.ampproject.org is a cache that belongs to Google. This cache is used for all views that happen in search and google news and many other apps including Bing etc. You are definitely not losing credit since they will all show you as the author and creator.